# Crashes and ANR on android developer, unknown classes

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

Today i've checked my crashes and ANR on my google play developer account, The thing is for every crash, The location of the error doesn't exist in my project. I'm getting something like:

> nameofpackage.ui.activities.ak.a

My package called activities doesn't have any class called ak, neither a !

*also:*

> nameofpackage.ui.chants.a.onClick

Chants also doesn't have a class called a ! 
is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Those names probably generated by `proguard`. if you have the line:

```
-printmapping out.map
```

Inside the rules file of `proguard` then you have file called:

```
out.map
```

In your project tree, there you can see what was the origin class of this `Exception`.

Comment: i checked my proguard file, but no i don't have such lines :/

Comment: i finally found that: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding , but where can i find the mapping.txt file!?

Comment: If you don't put this line before you don't have this file. You can take the project that you generate from it the APK file, and add the `-printmapping out.map` line, then regenarate the APK so you can get the map file that match the code.

Answer (score 0):

resolved, there is proguardgui which retrace the pile. You can fin it in:
sdk\tools\proguard\bin